# What is layout/template/themes in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new in codeigniter, I feel trouble about layout/template/themes in codeigniter. 

I don't know when should using one of them..

What is the best way that i can do? if i want to make a website with free a **html/css template** like

```
goodnatured
|--img
   |--img01.jpg
|--css
   |--style.css
|--js
   |--jquery.js
|--index.html
```

Anyone can tell me a tutorial, suggest, ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just write little additional library(`application/libraries/display_lib.php`) for rendering tempates and similar page blocks.
Something like this:

```
    class Display_Lib{
       private $_CI;
       private $_template_data;

       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->_CI =& get_instance();
       }

       public function set($key, $value)
       {
           $this->_template_data[$key] = $value;
       }

       public function get($key)
       {
           return $this->_template_data[$key];
       }

       public function get_template_data()
       {
           return $this->_template_data;
       }

       public function display_page($view, $data = array())
       {
           $this->set('content', $this->_CI->load->view($view, $data, TRUE));
           $this->_CI->load->view('templates/main_template', $this->get_template_data());
       }
}
```

Set this library in auto load:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database', 'display_lib');
```

And call it in controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        $some_data = array();
        $this->display_lib->display_page('views/main_view', $some_data);
    }
}
```

Template example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="<?=base_url();?>">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?=site_url('img/favicon.ico')?>" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=site_url('css/style.css');?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=site_url('js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');?>"></script>
    <title>Some page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="auth_wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <?=$content;?>
        </div>
        <div class="buffer"></div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And `application/views/main_view` simple exmaple:

```
<div>Come content will be here</div>
```

This lib allow to use templates and render views from controllers.

Comment: what the folder like? 
`application
   |--libraries
   |  |--display_lib.php
   |--controllers
   |  |--main.php
   |--views
      |--main_view.php
img
   |--img01.jpg
css
   |--style.css
js
   |--jquery.js`

Comment: Yes, your screen is correct display application structure, also need add `templates/main_template.php` to `views` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Templates handle the layout of your page. You create a template that will contain your meta, header, footer, and a space for the body. The body get injected in the template, this is where the content change.

The idea is that most of the site don't change, only the body changes. This is where templates are useful, they save you time and increase consistency.
See this template library, it's pretty good: http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show

Themes is combined with a template as templates often define the layout and a theme just 'skin' the layout. A theme include assets and styles that will modify the template further more.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Make a template.php, header.php, footer.php. Below is template.php, Similarly make header and footer and place them all in views folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="<?=site_url('img/favicon.ico')?>" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=site_url('css/style.css');?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=site_url('js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');?>"></script>
    <title>Some page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header><?=$this->load->view('header');?></header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <?=$main?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer><?=$this->load->view('footer');?></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

In your **Controller** function:

```
function index(){
    $data           = array();
    $data['main']   = "home";           #this view is home.php in views folder, the content part of template.php
    $this->load->view('template', $data); #this is the template file being rendered.
}
```

This is the most simple way of using templates in `CI` I think.

Comment: You didn't even change @joni's jQuery version `js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.

Comment: Used the `HTML` part but the logic is mine. It's in no way related to the other answer. @HashemQolami

Comment: It's bad practice and breaks MVC convention to load views from views. Consider using a layout or template library (here's mine: https://github.com/scotch-io/stencil) - or build your own. If you decide to do it this way, I suggest doing $data['header'] = $this->load->view('header', '', TRUE); Then passing that to your view to use as $header.

Comment: @envysea that mean this way ($this->load->view('header'), $this->load->view('content'), $this->load->view('footer')) is bad?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's bad. As long as it's only within the controller, that's a perfectly good way to do it. The question was regarding layouts and templates though. Returning the views content as a variable however gives you a little bit more robust control outside of the controller and inside your views. So if you working with front-end guys, they can manage the layout however they want inside the views without having to build the layout from within the controllers. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @envysea I search and read about `load multi view in one controller` and it's hard. That is your mean? Or that's using like in controller:  $data['header']   = "header"; $data['content']   = "content";           $data['footer']   = "footer";   $this->load->view('template', $data); and in views  call $header... ? What should i do now :(

Comment: @freestyle. The best way in my opinion is to use a template library like the other answer said. Alternatively, if you are doing it the way this answer suggested, these two are good ways: https://gist.github.com/ncerminara/6251524 or https://gist.github.com/ncerminara/6251613. Or checkout Stencil, the link I posted earlier comes out of the box ready to go with a full blown template system, comes with examples, and is very easy to use.