# Create template in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, kohana

In **Kohana** while creating the template in the website controller we define the template path like

`public $template = 'user/template';`

In Code Igniter,how can we define this template.

I need suggestions.

Comment: Read docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: Where i have to mention the public $template variable. And i need default template.

Comment: @mangala: in your controller's load view. code snippet: `$this->load->view('default', $data_array);` it will load view named `default.php`.

Comment: So i have to call this $this->load->view('default', $data_array); one in every action right?

Comment: Please, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18231097/1613335 for similar question

Comment: @Jones: thanks buddy.. actually my question is need to declare the global template file. I will use this template file in all over project. This template should contain header, footer and content. And i need to declare the global header and footer file also. In the every action i don't want to mention this template name and i should give the content file only... thats i am asking this one friend.. i am asking same like kohana..

Comment: You don't need to use template name for every action, you just call needed view in controller, please, see code ``Main::index()`` in my answer. The proposed structure is suitable for your purposes and it very similar to Kohana layout structure. Sorry, but i don't see serious differences

Comment: Take a look at the Kohana_Controller_Template class to see how Kohana implements the template. CodeIgniter can be set up in mostly the same way, but using CodeIgniter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Parser class (built in to Codeigniter)

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/parser.html

following the guide on the link above should sort you out :P